# Deprecation error for rails stopping me from launching rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing some open source stuff for the rails app https://github.com/publiclab/mapknitter  but when I try to launch the rails server using `rails s` I get the following error message:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Support for Rails versions before 4.2 is deprecated and will be removed from skylight 2.0. (called from require at /Users/bena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81)
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.22.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[SKYLIGHT] [1.7.2] Running Skylight in development mode. No data will be reported until you deploy your app.
(To disable this message for all local apps, run `skylight disable_dev_warning`.)
Exiting
/Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/bena/Documents/repos/ben-repos/mapknitter/config/database.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/activerecord-3.2.22.5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:84:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/activerecord-3.2.22.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/skylight-1.7.2/lib/skylight/probes.rb:119:in `require'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/skylight-1.7.2/lib/skylight/probes.rb:119:in `require'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/bena/Documents/repos/ben-repos/mapknitter/config/initializers/column_definition.rb:19:in `<class:ColumnDefinition>'
    from /Users/bena/Documents/repos/ben-repos/mapknitter/config/initializers/column_definition.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `each'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/bena/Documents/repos/ben-repos/mapknitter/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/skylight-1.7.2/lib/skylight/probes.rb:119:in `require'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/skylight-1.7.2/lib/skylight/probes.rb:119:in `require'
    from /Users/bena/Documents/repos/ben-repos/mapknitter/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/bena/Documents/repos/ben-repos/mapknitter/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/bena/Documents/repos/ben-repos/mapknitter/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/bena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Is the problem caused by the the version of rails I am using or the version of skylight or something else entirely?

I am using `ruby 2.4.6p354` and `rails 3.2.22.5`

I have installed and tried to switch to `rails 4.2.0` but that doesn't seem to be working, I think because in the gemfile there is a pessimistic version constraint of `gem "rails" ,"~>3.2"` but I could be completely wrong. I have been told not to change the gemfile.

Answer (score 1):

Check first line in error backtrace. You dont have /config/database.yml in your project

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   /Users/bena/Documents/repos/ben-repos/mapknitter/config/database.yml
>   (Errno::ENOENT)

Make sure you install everything from [Prerequisites](https://github.com/publiclab/mapknitter#prerequisites) and simply follow [Installation](https://github.com/publiclab/mapknitter#installation) guide